# Why I am getting StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values while creating a pivot table?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics

Suppose I have this (randomic) `df_bnb`:

```
      neighbourhood      room_type      price    minimum_nights       

0        Allen          Pvt room          38            5              
1        Arder       Entire home/apt      90            2              
2       Arrochar     Entire home/apt      90            2              
3       Belmont        Shared Room        15            1             
4      City Island   Entire home/apt     100            3
```

Every row represents an Airbnb's booking.

I hope to generate a `pivot_table` in which `Index` is the column `neighbourhood` and columns are others data frame columns `['room_type', 'price', 'minimun_nights']`.

I want entries of the abovementioned columns as `mean`, expect for `room_type` where I wish to have the `mode`. Like the following dataframe's example:

```
                      room_type                       price                     minimum_nights           
Allen          room type mode for Allen         price mean for Allen       mean min nights for Allen
Arder          room type mode for Arder         price mean for Arder       mean min nights for Arder       
Arrochar       room type mode for Arrochar      price mean for Arrochar    mean of min nights for Arrochar
Belmont        room type mode for Belmont       price mean for Belmont     mean of min nights for Belmont 
City Island    room type mode for City Island   price mean fot City Is.    mean of min nights for City Island
```

This is the code I try so far:

```
bnb_pivot = pd.pivot_table(bnb,
                           index = ['neighborhood'],
                           values = ['room_type', 'price', 
                                    'minimum_nights','number_of_reviews'],
                           aggfunc = {'room_type': statistics.mode,
                                      'price' : np.mean,
                                      'minimum_nights': np.mean,
                                 'number_of_reviews': np.mean})
```

This is the error that I am getting:

`StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values`

I try to search for other sources, but I don't how to treat `statistic.mode()` while creating a `pivot_table`.

Many thanks in advance for any helpful indication!

Comment: You have a distribution of room types with more than one mode. Function `statistics.mode` cannot handle this situation.

Comment: @DYZ since there are two modes, I suppose it is not relevant the one to choose, right?

Comment: It is not. But `statistics.mode` _cannot_ handle more than one more. Read the documentation.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I just wanted to understand it from a statistical pov. Do you know any alternative method?

Comment: Pandas has its own `mode` method. It does not have that problem, I believe.